# How to best Upload Large Files to RStudio using Louis Aslett's AMI on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, bigdata, rstudio, rstudio-server

I would like to upload a huge file (50GB .csv) to Amazon EC2 RStudio set-up in order to make some statistical calculations.

I do only hve little experience with unix/linux. Is there a way to upload directly within RStudio?

Thanks!

Comment: RStudio Server doesn't handle file uploads from local directly. Its working environment is relative to the file system it's installed on (the EC2). For cost and convenience, you should probably look at uploading / storing the file on S3 and configuring the EC2/RStudio to read from it.

Comment: Is there an easy way on how to configure the EC2/RStudio to read from S3. Any experiences/ best practices? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First make your file in S3 public by selecting the file and then select Make public from the drop down- **Action**, right click the file for properties and copy the link (http://s3-us-west....)and then read the csv file as below 
a <- read.csv("link", header=TRUE)